# Trying to figure out some basic twitter functions with type script. I have no idea why this runs, but doesn't retweet tweets containing #100DaysOfCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, twitter

Help appreciated. I really have no clue what going on. I also have never used typescript or JavaScript before. The code runs on loop, but it just doesn't actually retweet anything containing the hashtag

```
import Twit, { Response } from 'twit';

const Twitter = new Twit(require('./config'));

const mediaArtsSearch: Twit.Params = {
  q: '#100DaysOfCode',
  count: 100,
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
  result_type: 'recent',
};

const retweetLatest = () => {
  Twitter.get('search/tweets', mediaArtsSearch, (error: Error, data: any) => {
    console.log(error, data);
    if (!error) {
      const retweetId = data.statuses[0].id_str;     //finds id of tweet, labels it as retweetid
      Twitter.post(
        'statuses/retweet/' + retweetId,            //retweets the tweet
        {},
        (error: Error, response: Response) => {
          if (response) {
            console.log(
              'Success! Check your bot, it should have retweeted something.',
            );
          }
          if (error) {
            console.log('There was an error with Twitter:', error);
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      console.log('There was an error with your hashtag search:', error);
    }
  });
};

retweetLatest();
setInterval(retweetLatest, 1000 * 20);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you get ? Do you see any console logs indicating success (in getting or retweetting) without seeing the actual tweets on twitter ? Or do you get some errors on those requests?

Comment: i just get a bunch of this:
There was an error with Twitter: Error: Read-only application cannot POST.
    at Object.exports.makeTwitError (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\twit\lib\helpers.js:74:13)
    at onRequestComplete (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:344:25)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\twit\lib\twitter.js:364:7)
    at Request.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wooki\your-next-project\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)

Comment: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: null,
  allErrors: [
    {
      request: '/1.1/statuses/retweet/1436742109759934466.json',
      error: 'Read-only application cannot POST.'
    }
  ],
  twitterReply: {
    request: '/1.1/statuses/retweet/1436742109759934466.json',
    error: 'Read-only application cannot POST.'
  },
  statusCode: 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error messages you added in the comments are pretty clear : there is an authorization issue.
The way you are calling the twitter API does allow you to **GET** (search tweets...) but not to **POST** tweets.

There might be several causes:

- You are not adding (correctly?) authentication element to your request (Token etc.).
- Your account's email is waiting for validation.
- You have to allow "read+write" in your twitter developer acccount settings. And even if read+write is already selected, you may have to click it again (as explained below):

> In case this helps anyone else: The twitter dev page already showed read+write access for my app, but the authorization request still only requested read access. I had to click on "read+write" in the dev settings again (despite it already being selected), then click on save. This seems to be a bug on the twitter side of things, probably triggered by the recent API changes.

(found here: https://github.com/DocNow/diffengine/issues/20#issuecomment-807864651)

Comment: holy wow thank you man, this bailed me out. I went into the dev settings like u said and changed to read and write, then regenerated all my tokens. Thank you so much, sorry u had to help I should've noticed this

Comment: @WnnaC-Mypython Ok, then you can vote this answer up and *accept it* (green tick).